# SQL Joining of Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sum

SQL newbie here, I am trying to have the table print out the sum of the wages, make, and car model for all the people that own a particular make/model combination.  As of right now, the table prints out all the Car Make and Model values, but the SumWage column is all NULL. The SumWage should return the total sum of all the wages of people who have the Make/Model combination.(My select statement is all the way at the bottom of the code)?  All advice is much appreciated!

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('Person', 'U') IS NULL 

BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE Person (
        ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        Name VARCHAR(32),
        BirthDate DATETIME 
        );

    INSERT INTO Person
        ( ID, Name, BirthDate )
    VALUES
        (311113, 'Dan Lu', '01-22-33'), 
        (123456, 'Seven Durant', '07-22-94'), 
        (100100, 'Choochootrain Lu', '12-17-56'),
        (106542, 'Spider Ru', '07-22-36'),
        (101010, 'Ru Ru', '04-30-84');
END

IF OBJECT_ID ('Job', 'U') IS NULL 

BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE Job (
        ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        Company VARCHAR(64),
        Wage FLOAT,
        PersonID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(ID)
        );

    INSERT INTO Job
        ( ID, Company, Wage, PersonID )
    VALUES
        (01, 'Space Pizza Space', 1000.00, 311113), 
        (02, 'Bread', 46.44, 101010), 
        (03, 'Delivery Service', 400.99, 100100), 
        (04, 'Nike', 999900.01, 106542), 
        (05, 'Old McDonald', 6500210.77, 123456);
END


IF OBJECT_ID ('Car', 'U') IS NULL 

BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE Car (
        ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        Make VARCHAR(32),
        Model VARCHAR(32)       
        );

    INSERT INTO Car
        ( ID, Make, Model )
    VALUES
        (1234, 'Lexus', 'SE'), 
        (4444, 'Tesla', 'X'), 
        (5007, 'Chevy', 'Cobalt'),
        (7771, 'Ford', 'Runner'),
        (6459, 'Toyota', 'Camry');
END

IF OBJECT_ID ('PersonCar', 'U') IS NULL 

BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE PersonCar (
        ID INT,
        PersonID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(ID),
        CarID INT       
        );

    INSERT INTO PersonCar
        ( ID, PersonID, CarID )
    VALUES
        (1, 311113, 1234), 
        (2, 123456, 4444), 
        (3, 100100, 5007),
        (4, 106542, 7771),
        (5, 101010, 6459);
END

SELECT SUM(Wage) AS SumWages, Car.Make, Car.Model
FROM Person
    INNER JOIN PersonCar 
        ON PersonCar.ID = Person.ID
    INNER JOIN Job 
        ON Job.PersonID = PersonCar.ID 
    Right JOIN Car
        ON Car.ID = Person.ID
GROUP BY Wage, Make, Model;
```

Comment: Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. There's no such clear statement here, and when you write one, it will be a faq.

Comment: A [mre] isn't just code that doesn't work. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.) Say what you expected & why you expected it. Because your expectations are wrong & that's what we need to address. Eg Input fewer rows & look at select * of each join result & then the group by. PS Give up your overall goal, find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
SELECT SUM(j.Wage) AS SumWages, c.Make, c.Model
FROM Car c
LEFT JOIN PersonCar pc ON pc.CarID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN Job j ON j.PersonID = pc.PersonID
GROUP BY c.Make, c.Model;
```

This selects all `Car`s, and follows the relationships towards the Job table, that contains the `Wage` of each car owner. Data is aggregated by car model and model, and the corresponding wages are sumed.

When a given make/model tuple has no car owner, the sum comes out as `null` (if you want to just remove these rows from the resultset, use `INNER JOIN`s instead of `LEFT JOIN`s).

Note that you don't need to bring the `Person` table to get this resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Hey it looks like there are a couple errors with your JOINs
See if switching what you JOIN "ON" like below and changing the last JOIN from a RIGHT to an INNER will do for you.

```
SELECT
  SUM(Job.Wage) AS SumWages
  , Car.Make
  , Car.Model
FROM
  Person
   INNER JOIN PersonCar 
    ON PersonCar.PersonID = Person.ID
   INNER JOIN Job 
    ON Job.PersonID = PersonCar.ID 
   INNER JOIN Car
    ON Car.ID = PersonCar.CarID
GROUP BY SumWages, Make, Model
;
```